# What is a proper way to disable a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a tkinter application with 2 buttons. `Run application` and `Store data`. I don't want to give the end-user the opportunity to click `Store data` if he has not clicked `Run application` first.

So the button `Store data` needs to get un-disabled after the button `Run application` has been clicked first.

In my code below I have created a `checker` function which is supposed to do above, however the `Store data` button always stays disabled.

**This is my code:**

```
import os
from tkinter import *

owner = ['Spain', 'United Kingdom', 'Malaysia']

path_spain = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\spain_software.py"
path_uk = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\uk_software.py"
path_malaysia = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\malaysia_software.py"

window = Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script")  # Create window
window.geometry('550x300')  # geo of the window

data = []
#Confirmation function
def store():
    data.append(dd_owner.get())
    print(data)
    checker()

def run():
    if dd_owner.get() == "Spain":
        print("spain")
        # os.system('python path_spain')
    elif dd_owner.get() == "United Kingdom":
        os.system('python path_uk')

    elif dd_owner.get() == "Malaysia":
        os.system('python path_malaysia')

def update_button(_):
    run_button.config(text="Run application {}".format(dd_owner.get()))

# These are the option menus
dd_owner = StringVar(window)
w = OptionMenu(window, dd_owner, *owner, command=update_button)
w.grid(row=0, column=1)

#These are the buttons
store_button =Button(window, text="Store data!",command=store)
store_button.grid(column=0, row=31)

run_button = Button(window, text="Run application {}".format(dd_owner.get()), bg="blue", fg="white",command=run)
run_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

# These are the titles
l1 = Label(window, text='Select Owner', width=15)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

def checker():
    if data:
        store_button.configure(state='normal')
    else:
        store_button.configure(state='disabled')


checker()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually you should enable the button inside `run()` if the required condition is matched and `checker()` is not necessary.

Comment: @Atlas435 no it does not.

Comment: @acw1668 can you show me by code?

Comment: @TangerCity place `store_button.configure(state='normal')` inside your `run` function.

Comment: If no owner is selected, should the store button be kept disabled even run button is clicked?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232816/discussion @acw1668 join in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two buttons should be disabled initially.

Then if owner is selected, enable "Run" button.

If "Run" button is clicked, enable "Store" button.

Below is a modified example:

```py
import os
from tkinter import *

owner = ['Spain', 'United Kingdom', 'Malaysia']

path_spain = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\spain_software.py"
path_uk = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\uk_software.py"
path_malaysia = r"c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\malaysia_software.py"

window = Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script")  # Create window
window.geometry('550x300')  # geo of the window

data = []
#Confirmation function
def store():
    owner = dd_owner.get()
    if owner and owner not in data:
        data.append(owner)
        print(data)

def run():
    if dd_owner.get() == "Spain":
        print("spain")
        # os.system('python path_spain')
    elif dd_owner.get() == "United Kingdom":
        os.system('python path_uk')
    elif dd_owner.get() == "Malaysia":
        os.system('python path_malaysia')
    # enable store button
    store_button.config(state="normal")

def update_button(_):
    # update text and enable the button
    run_button.config(text="Run application {}".format(dd_owner.get()), state="normal")

# These are the option menus
dd_owner = StringVar(window)
w = OptionMenu(window, dd_owner, *owner, command=update_button)
w.grid(row=0, column=1)

#These are the buttons
store_button =Button(window, text="Store data!", command=store, state="disabled") # initially disabled
store_button.grid(column=0, row=31)

run_button = Button(window, text="Run application {}".format(dd_owner.get()),
                    bg="blue", fg="white",command=run, state="disabled") # initially disabled
run_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

# These are the titles
l1 = Label(window, text='Select Owner', width=15)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, can you join the chat again? I have some questions about your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
Button(root,state= DISABLED)
```

This will disable.

then -

```
Button(root,state= NORMAL)
```

This will enable the button

Don't use '' or "". Just write in CAPITAL

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `if data:`

Data is a list. You can't use Data as a boolean in the if statement.